# Вывод в label с задержкой

Tags: objective-c, многопоточность

Доброй ночи, пытаюсь выводить в лейбл текст посимвольно,делаю это в отдельном потоке, но почему то текст в метке появляется весь сразу, а не посимвольно, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать верно или что исправить?
Создаю поток так:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector (TestMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

-(void) TestMethod
{
NSString *s = textplace.text;
int i = textplace.text.length;
label1.text = @"";
for(int j =0;j < i;j++)
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(j, 1);
    label1.text = [label1.text stringByAppendingString:[s substringWithRange:range]];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
}
[NSThread exit];
```

}

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить интервал:     NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1000]

Мне кажется, там указываются микросекунды, а не секунды.

Comment: NSTimeInterval всегда в секундах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не можете ничего делать c UI находясь не в MainThread, запомните это, это может быть причиной некорректной работы или даже падений. Попробуйте, находясь в Main Thread

```
[self.label performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:newText afterDelay:5.0];
```

**обновлю ответ, чтобы было понятнее:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < newText.length; i++) {
     [self.label performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[newText substringToIndex:i] afterDelay:i*2.0];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за момент с UI, но к сожалению Ваш вариант выдает тот же результат что и мой, 

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    [label1 performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]     afterDelay:2.0];
    }
выдаст сразу 3 в метке, а не 1,2,3 поочередно, как хотелось бы

Comment: правильно, потому что цикл выполняется очень быстро. Попробуйте где то так

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
      [label1 performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]     afterDelay:(i*2)];
    }

Comment: Спасибо!Так работает, а можно уточнить, почему если указать как сделали вы то будет работать, а если к примеру

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    [label1 performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]       afterDelay:5.0];
    }
то через 5 сек появится моя тройка опять же сразу а в вашем варианте все как надо, что за магия?) Ведь по сути вы просто задали время переменной, а я сразу константой.

Comment: вам необходимо увеличивать интервал, i*2 при каждом шаге цикла будет все больше, соответственно вы отложенно запускаете метод setText: 4 раза с задержками 0, 2, 4, 6 секунд, отсюда и такой эффект. В вашем случае вы 4 раза вызываете setText: через 2 секунды

Comment: Спасибо огромное!То что нужно!